# Sitecore Error: Could not get pipeline: initialize (domain: )

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore8, sitecore7.2, sitecore-mvc

I am getting below error with my Sitecore website.

[image]

Can someone please help on it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add some more information. Has it worked before? Have you changed something? Do you see it in content editor / page editor / everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably trying to patch the pipeline before it's actually getting initialized.

Put your config under /app_config/zzz/yourfile.config

Then it'll be guaranteed to run after the pipeline is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You have either overwritten or corrupted the Sitecore default Web.config (prior to Sitecore 8.1) or removed/corrupted the App_Config\Sitecore.config (Sitecore 8.1).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,You could check for the NEXUS DLL whether it is added or not.If added check for the compatibility i,e the version of the DLL that is used and the supported version in your project.

Secondly,Do check for the "/configuration/sitecore/pipelines" section of the web.config.